# How to convert an int array used as a kind of BigInteger to a "human readable" String?

Tags: java, string, debugging, math, biginteger

I'm trying to implement some functionality of `BigInteger`s as a personal programming exercise.

Like many implementations I use an `int[]` as an unsigned integer.

I want to implement basic functionality like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, but I'm hitting the problem that I need to get a "human readable" `toString` out of my data structure for debug purposes, so that I can better inspect and understand what I'm doing.

I feel like I'm stuck. I'm not confident that my algorithms are right, but I have no way to check it.

I have looked at some implementations like Apache Harmony or OpenJDK, but the algorithms they use to create the String look more complex than the actual implementation of plus, minus, ... and so on.

Of course I could just use one of those complicated ones, but I would at least want to be able to understand the implementation of it, if I already fail at implementing it myself.

Can someone suggest a simple implementation which converts an `int[]` to a String?

Example: `new int[]{Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1}` should be treated as one large, unsigned number and print: `8589934590` (So basically 2³³).

Comment: Could you give a couple of examples of `int[]`s and the expected output strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this approach:

- You don't mention how you store zero; it may need special handling, in which case you can special-case it before proceeding with the rest of the algorithm.
- Make a copy of the `int[]`; call it `iArr`. The rest of this algorithm will operate on `iArr`.
- Create a `char[]` — call it `s` — that is big enough. Since an `int` can have up to ten digits, you can use `s = new char[iArr.length * 10]`.
- Start at position `int i = s.length - 1`. Go through `iArr`, dividing by ten, and store the remainder plus `'0'` in `s[i]`. Then decrement `i`. Repeat this process until `iArr` is zero. (The logic for dividing by ten is roughly: divide each element by ten, noting the remainder. Add that remainder, times `Integer.MAX_INT + 1`, to the next element, before dividing *that* element by ten. Needless to say, you'll need to do your math using `long`.)
- Your result is `new String(s, i, s.length - i)`.

For efficiency's sake:

- You can potentially divide by a power of ten, such as `1000000` or whatnot, to get a bunch of digits at once (obviously this makes the `char`-handling trickier, though).
- As you zero-out leading elements of `iArr`, you can keep track of where the first non-zero element is, and ignore any elements before that.

but neither of those is actually necessary.

---

**Edited to add** actual code. This program:

```
public class Main
{
    private static final long RADIX = -2L * (long)Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{0})); // 0
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{1})); // 1
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{Integer.MAX_VALUE})); // 2^31-1
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{Integer.MIN_VALUE})); // 2^31
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{-1})); // 2^32-1
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{1, 0})); // 2^32
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{1, -1})); // 2^33-1
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{-1, -1})); // 2^64-1
        System.out.println(stringify(new int[]{1, 0, 0})); // 2^64
    }

    private static String stringify(final int[] _iArr)
    {
        final int[] iArr = new int[_iArr.length];
        System.arraycopy(_iArr, 0, iArr, 0, _iArr.length);
        final char[] ret = new char[10 * iArr.length];
        int retIndex = ret.length;
        while(true)
        {
            boolean isZero = true;
            int carry = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < iArr.length; ++i)
            {
                long val = unsignedInt2Long(iArr[i]);
                if(val != 0L)
                    isZero = false;
                val += carry * RADIX;
                carry = (int) (val % 10L);
                val /= 10L;
                iArr[i] = long2UnsignedInt(val);
            }
            if(isZero)
            {
                if(retIndex == ret.length)
                    return "0";
                else
                    return new String(ret, retIndex, ret.length - retIndex);
            }
            assert(retIndex > 0);
            ret[--retIndex] = (char) (carry + (int)'0');
        }
    }

    private static long unsignedInt2Long(final int unsignedInt)
    {
        if(unsignedInt >= 0)
            return unsignedInt;
        else
            return unsignedInt + RADIX;
    }

    private static int long2UnsignedInt(final long _long)
    {
        assert(_long >= 0L);
        assert(_long < RADIX);
        if(_long <= (long) Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            return (int) _long;
        else
            return (int) (_long - RADIX);
    }
}
```

prints this:

```
0
1
2147483647
2147483648
4294967295
4294967296
8589934591
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551616
```

(But you'll have to examine the `main` method, with its comments, to confirm that I've correctly understood how you intend to store these integers.)

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'll try to implement that! Which order does your implementation assume? Is `digits[0]` the least or the most significant position? Is there a recommended way to implement it?

Comment: `s[0]` is the most significant position (since that's what `new String(...)` expects).

Comment: *sigh* I can't get it to work :-( I feel like I'm completely stupid ... could you show me how the loop should look like?

Comment: @soc: Can you give me a precise definition of how you're storing these integers? You say that you're storing an "unsigned integer". Does this mean that every element of your array will be positive? Or does it mean that you're using an offset of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (so, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` means zero, zero means `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` means `2 * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`)? Or something different?

Comment: @soc: Also, is this "little-endian", or "big-endian"? Like, is `{1,0}` equivalent to `{1}` (little-endian: LSB first), or is `{0,1}` equivalent to `{1}` (big-endian: MSB first)?

Comment: I store a sign bit somewhere else. So the numbers are really unsigned. If the sign is -1, I add a '-' later before printing. I think I'm using BigEndian.

Comment: @soc: Java doesn't have unsigned integers, so I'm still stuck on what you mean by "really unsigned". I gave two possibilities for what you might mean . . . is either of them correct?

Comment: The int is treated as unsigned. So 0 is 0, 1 is 1 and Int.MinValue is 2³².

Comment: @soc: Sorry, but that's not possible. Integers are 32 bits in Java; so if you treat them as unsigned, the maximum possible value is 2³²-1. Maybe you mean that `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is 2³¹? It's stored as 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000, so that would make sense.

Comment: @soc: I've edited my answer to add a program that stringifies my best-guess interpretation of how you're storing these values. If I've guessed wrong, you'll have to change the `stringify` method, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I meant, I'll try your code shortly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Start by implementing a converter to hex, and use hex as your human-readable format during the initial stages of development. Doing HEX is easy, because you do not need to implement division: simply convert individual items to HEX, glue them together, and you are done.

Once your division algorithm is in place, you can implement conversion to decimal format by the usual "get the remainder % 10 and divide away" approach.